# My Android app is not showing in playstore for Samsung tablets(With Kitkat os)

Tags: android, google-play-services

My Android App is not showing  in Playstore for Samsung Tablets(KitKat os).But it is working for all the os except kitkat.What is the problem with KitKat?Can any one please help me.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <permission
    android:name="com.xxxxxxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" >
</permission>
<permission
    android:name="com.xxxxxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.xxxxxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.xxxxxxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Comment: are you able to install on KitKat version?

Comment: We did n't test it on kitkat

Comment: Can you post your manifest file of your application ?

Comment: Can you please check the manifest file -lonut Negru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

target sdk version should be

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

and also add this

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
```

I hope this will solve your problem.
Bskania.